# Updating table from JSON/MYSQL with jQuery

Tags: php, mysql, json, real-time

I'm curious as to what the most acceptable/effective approach is to using tables with data from json.

I have one project in development where I need to update individual cells of a table, based on a mysql table. 
My X axis labels would be assorted dates (also pulled from mysql).
The Y axis labels are times (These are always the same and as such could be generated statically).
The content of the table would be available appointment slots (also pulled from mysql).

This table is purely reading off of mysql, as such does need to update the table. I need to refresh the table contents every 15 seconds (without refreshing the page obviously). So my question what is the best way to give reference each cell so I can programatically update them with my json output. This would also need the ability to remove a column if a day has been removed from the appointment roster.

Any assistance would simply be amazing.

Comment: A quick example would help us all to talk about the same thing

Comment: This is a quick mock up, completely unstyled of what I want to achieve. [link]http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/6706/capturefok.png 

The dates up top could change fairly regularly. The numbers represent number of appointments available, with 'X's indicating no more appointments.

This calendar of sorts isn't linked directly to actual individual appointments, it's purely a counter.

Comment: Do you only need to display the number of appointments by cell ?

Comment: No, I need the entire table to refresh every 15 seconds or so

Comment: In that case you could get all the records each time from the server. So no need to compare the client/server data. You could redraw the entire table every 15sec. Is it big ?

Comment: No, it's not! The screen shot I provided is about the maximum size. Would the most effective way of doing that be just updating the html contents of the <table> tag? (using jQuery)

Comment: I think it would be simpler, because the table is not that big. I'm going to change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

Your table generation:

```
<?php
// example for one col
while($array = mysql_fetchassoc($result))
{
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td id="col_name_<?=$array['row_id']?>"><?=$array['col_val']?></td>
    </tr>
    <?
}
?>
```

Your AJAX respond should look like this

```
<?php
while($array = mysql_fetchassoc($result))
{
    ?>
      $('#col_name_<?=$array['row_id']?>').html('<?=$array['col_val']?>');
    <?
}
?>
```

Comment: He asked for a solution to update a table cell with jQuery. Not that it must be done with JSON. The idea is still the same. He could recieve the data JSON encoded and use my second code in JS only to update the cells.

Comment: You mean you want send the table with JSON once built with php ?

Comment: If he wants to have a good performance, he still need more checks. You have got good ideas for that in your answer. You are right, that he don't have to update ALL cells evertime. I thought, that he'll get this point by himself. I've just gave him a hint to solve his problem with the construction of the table and updating it with jQuery.

Comment: Cheers, I haven't currently got ID numbers for my rows, I was aiming to do this without them, as I have no other need for them. Might just add them in. Is there anythinhg majorly wrong with adding your own attribute to each cell?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key features are

- javascript `setTimeout()` to fetch data every 15sec.
- a kind of hash comparison between client & server data to see if there is a modification
- a php function that extract just the modifications to apply
- a javascript to update the appointments sent by JSON

Maybe you should use a calendar tool for rendering.
[Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) is a pretty good open-source solution for that.

For the updates, I would approach this by presenting the data like:

```
appointment_id, timestamp_start, timestamp_end, ...
```

With that you can know if the appointment already exists or if it's a modification (update or delete)
You can also deduce the dates to display

---

**Edit**

Since your table is not that big and always day/hour based, this will be much simpler to manage:

Javascript `setTimeout()` to fetch data every 15sec,
Retrieve the entire table by JSON,
Load it by building up the HTML with jQuery like:

```
table = $('#table_container');
/* data -> appointments indexed by hours/days fetched by JSON
 * x -> days, y -> hours
 */
for (y=0; data[y].length; y++) {
  tr = $('<tr />');
  table.append(tr);
  for (x=0; data[y][x]; x++) {
    td = $('<td />');
    td.html(data[y][x]);
    tr.append(td);
  }
}
```

*not tested but rough idea*

Comment: Thanks mate, that plugin actually looks to complex for what I want to do. I was wondering if you could elaborate though, on how the hash comparison would work. Or if you could point me in the right direction of online resources.